# Performace degraded when loading more then 10 models in world wind

Tags: worldwind

I am working on a project in which i need to load around 100 models of ship and aircraft on world wind AppFrame Viewport.

I have used ColladaRoot and ColladaSource classes for the same purpose.

the whole project is divided into these files:

a. TrackGenerator: generates ship or aircraft positions at every 2 sec.

b. TrackModel: The model for each of these ship an aircraft.

c: Track: Stores all the position data and type of the track.

d: TrackViewer:subclassed from AppFrame for the wwj display.

Flow of calling: TrackGenerator creates or update a track-->Update take place in the model after 2 second timer.

My problem is related to optimization as when the no of tracks exceeds 10 it starts lagging the GUI.

So what optimization changes i can perform in the code.

Model Used for ship(Only 1)
https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=ff0e0185c173be45b8cf818b5958b8b7

for AirCraft(More then 1)
https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=ue64c6952-ffa1-4647-9ae5-533d964317d6

hardware

32 GB RAM

Graphics card quadro K6000

OctCore 2.6 ghz

Comment: Those models have pretty high polygon counts for loading so many into world wind, can you reduce the polygon count?

Comment: Thanks I have tried it with light models then it works fine.